# Login PDO PHP com prepare

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tendo problemas com o Login
Não aparece nenhum erro, porém parece que o programa para ao tentar fazer o select

```php
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include("conn.php");
$conexao = getConnection();

$referer = $_POST['referer']; /*redirlogin*/
$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$lembrar = $_POST['lembrar'];
//-------------------------------- COOKIE ini ------------------------------------
if($_COOKIE["usuario_PROJECT"] == '' && $_COOKIE["senha_PROJECT"] == ''){
    //-------------------------- COOCKIE ---------------------------------------
    if($lembrar == 1){
        setcookie("usuario_PROJECT",$_SESSION['usuario'], time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
        setcookie("senha_PROJECT",$_SESSION['senha'], time()+60*60*24*365, '/');
    }else{
        setcookie("usuario_PROJECT",$_SESSION['usuario']);
        setcookie("senha_PROJECT",$_SESSION['senha']);
    }
    //cookie('web', 'ano', time()+1000, '/', '.luxweb.sk')  
}
//setcookie("usuario_PEM", $_SESSION['usuario'], time()+60*60*24*365, "/coluna/php/", "www.imasters.com.br",1); 
//-------------------------------- COOKIE fim ------------------------------------

?>

<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title> Autenticando Usuario </title>
</head>

<body>
```

Talvez seja esta parte:

```php
<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM login_tab WHERE usuario = :usuario AND senha = :senha";
$stmt = $conexao->prepare($sql2);
$stmt = bimdParam(':usuario',$usuario);
$stmt = bimdParam(':senha',$senha);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
//$row = $stmt->rowCount();

foreach($result as $ln)      
{  
    $perfil = $ln['perfil'];
    echo $ativo = $ln['ativo'];
}
```

```php
if($ativo == 1){

    $_SESSION['usuario']=$_POST['usuario'];
    $_SESSION['senha']=$_POST['senha'];

    //-------------------------- COOCKIE ---------------------------------------
    if($lembrar == 1){
        setcookie("sistema_project_cookie_login", $_SESSION['usuario'], time()+ 31536000);
        setcookie("sistema_project_cookie_senha", $_SESSION['senha'], time()+ 31536000);
    }else{
        setcookie("sistema_project_cookie_login", $_SESSION['usuario']);
        setcookie("sistema_project_cookie_senha", $_SESSION['senha']);
    }
    //-------------------------- COOCKIE ---------------------------------------


    /* redirlogin */    
    if($referer == ""){
        echo"<script>location.href = 'index.php'</script>";}
    else {
            echo"<script>location.href =".$referer."'</script>"; 
    }

}
    else{
            echo '<script language= "JavaScript">location.href="login.php#erro'.$perfil.'"</script>';
        }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Desde já Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O problema está aqui:

> echo $ativo = $ln['ativo'];

o certo seria

> echo $ln["ativo"];

ou

> $ativo $ln["ativo"];
>
> echo $ln["ativo"];

Comment: Eu tinha colocado o echo pra ver se ta pegando a informação, porém não esta.
nenhuma das alternativas funcionou :/